# Dealing up with lot Amazon SNS notification in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I'm developing email campain system which use Amazon services: SES for sending emails, SNS for recieving statistics. And I ran into a problem when I start large campaign with 10k emails. SES succesfully sends all of them but SNS with 10k SEND and 10k DELIVERY notifications loads my server's CPU and RAM to 100%. And now I am looking for solution how can I minimize amount of notifications, maybe group them and not receive them one by one every time they occurred.
I am running Laravel with aws-sdk-php on Nginx with MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Send notifications/reports to queue and process them at your own desired pace.